# Thermal likelihood formula

Tags: meteorology

Background: I use the X-Plane flightsimulator for flying and gliding. In the program we have real weather (clouds, winds, etc...) but thermals are not well implemented, they don't have any connection with clouds or weather, they are just blue thermals. We can control its altitude, climb rate and coverage (percentage). I am thinking about writing a small plugin to control these preferences based on the real weather.

Can you give a simple formula to roughly calculate thermal parameters based on data in METARs (temperature, drew point, cloud coverage/type, wind). Thanks!

Comment: I would just calculate the vertical velocity using the vertical momentum equation  and examine it's value. Negative values represent lift and positive subsidence.

Comment: Boundary Layer Method by Roland Stull check that book out

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll check the book out, but since I'm not if physics, it's possible that I'll not understand a word!:) I found this: https://www.meteoblue.com/hu/id%C5%91j%C3%A1r%C3%A1s/el%C5%91rejelz%C3%A9s/thermal/budapest_magyarorsz%C3%A1g_3054643 that had indexes and so in it. I don't need anything complicated and precise just some heuristic to determine the thermal coverage percentage and so.

Comment: the meteoblue link you provided does talk about vertical velocity.  The formula for soaring index is here - https://www.ssa.org/files/member/Methodology.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems that this hole is deeper than I thought...

Comment: you have a problem in dynamics. I am not sure how an equation that does not involve (or a prognostic)  time can lead you to the right answer. Cloud formation(or not) is an inherently dynamic (time dependent) process.

Comment: I was hoping some heuristics based on sentences from the above mentioned web-page like this: "A larger difference between temperature and dewpoint means less humidity and thus a higher cloud base." and "Thermals develop under calm conditions or with light, variable wind. However, with 10 to 20 km/h wind, the thermals tend to be better organized. Stronger winds generally means also more wind above, which could produce wind shear, destroying the thermals. Look at the wind shear diagram. "

Comment: the thing is these parameters change dynamically. You can calculate the temperature at a particular point say 30 meters above the surface. Few minutes later a cold air blows and the temperature falls. So a dynamical model is always better than a static model

Comment: In my plugin a was planned to calculate these let's say every 5 minutes from the available latest METAR then update the thermal settings accordingly.

Comment: METAR is just a bunch of observations. You need to add that to a model and let the model tell you whether the thermal cloud will form or not.

Comment: Model or formula, what is the difference?

Comment: you are asking for a prognostic output. Will the thermal form or not in the future? That is the job of a model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94579/discussion-between-gansub-and-stone).